# Bootstrap 4 Modal In A PHP ForEach Loop

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, bootstrap-4

Im trying to fix a strange error with my code with the Bootstrap 4 Modal code.  I've simply just copied and pasted the code from here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events

This is for an automotive website and Im trying to pass stock and VIN via the data attribute as requested.  The question is how this works with a foreach loop.  It works on a single Wordpress page or post but won't pull the data from each section of the loop.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-stock="<?php echo $vehicle['stock_number'];?>">Check Availability</button>
```

```
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Stock</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my Jquery code
(function($) {

````
$('#exampleModal').on('modal.fade.show', function (event) {
    alert( "clicked" );
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('stock') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use $ here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})})( jQuery );```
````

Functionality wise this works, just not within the dynamic pages that are being generated in the foreach loop. The buttons have the proper data-attribute applied but the data doesn't seem to pass to the modal from the loop. I have a development page up where you can take a live look here, the button in question is the "Check Availability" http://windsor.sixomedia.ca/inventory/New/

Comment: Does the Modal ID need to have a number attached to it?  So it would be ExampleModal1, ExampleModal2, ExampleModal3?  I thought this was solved with jQuery passing the data variables to it.  I can get it working attaching a different ID to each modal box but this seems not necessary (or am I wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var recipient = button.data('data-stock');
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, tried that to unfortunately no change.  I created a separate test page https://windsor.sixomedia.ca/test/ and functionality works fine which is making me super confused on what effect the php foreach loop has on this.